# AngularJS display data record one at a time by id

Tags: angularjs

I am brand new to AngularJS and I'm figuring this is pretty easy, but I can't find out how to do it by searching the web.  I want to have a textbox, that a user can enter an order number into, and then bring up the data associated with that ordernumber.  I have the following controller that has some dummy data in it.

```
(function () {

'use strict';

angular
  .module('crm.ma')
  .controller('LookUpCtrl', LookUpCtrl)
  .filter('lookupFilter', function (){});

function LookUpCtrl($filter) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.results = [
        {
            accountId: 1,
            accountName: 'some name',
            address: '201 some st',
            city: 'Columbus',
            state: 'OH',
            zip: 'zip',
            phone: '899-629-7645',
            parentName: 'Parent 1',
            accountType: 'Type 1',
            accountStatus: 'Status 1',
            creditTerm: 'Term 1',
            ordernumber: '34567'
        },
        {
            accountId: 2,
            accountName: 'house home',
            address: '2963 this st',
            city: 'Columbus',
            state: 'OH',
            zip: 'zip',
            phone: '899-627-7592',
            parentName: 'Parent 2',
            accountType: 'Type 2',
            accountStatus: 'Status 2',
            creditTerm: 'Term 2',
            ordernumber: '43228'
        }
    ];
}
}());
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

SO you want to see what I've already got:  Here is a table that I created that uses ng-repeat to display all records.  I used a filter to be able to search the table and display records based on the search.  With what I want to do now, I want to enter in a specific order# and bring up one result.

```
<div ng-controller="LookUpCtrl as vm">
<div>Lookup Results</div>
<div><input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" ng-model="query" /></div>
<table ng-if="query">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Acc. ID</th>
            <th>Acc. Name</th>
            <th>Acc Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Parent Name</th>
            <th>Account Type</th>
            <th>Account Status</th>
            <th>Credit Term</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-show="results.length!=0" ng-repeat="result in vm.results | filter:query ">
            <td data-th="Acc. ID">{{ result.accountId }}</td>
            <td data-th="Acc. Name">{{ result.accountName }}</td>
            <td data-th="Acc Address">{{ result.address }}</td>
            <td data-th="City">{{ result.city }}</td>
            <td data-th="State">{{ result.state }}</td>
            <td data-th="Zip">{{ reuslt.zip }}</td>
            <td data-th="Phone">{{ result.phone }}</td>
            <td data-th="Parent Name">{{ result.parentName }}</td>
            <td data-th="Account Type">{{ result.accountType }}</td>
            <td data-th="Account Status">{{ result.accountStatus }}</td>
            <td data-th="Credit Term">{{ result.creditTerm }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-show="results.length==0">
                (0) Results found for AccountID {{ result.accountId }}, Order Number {{ result.ordernumber }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you need to use any one of many filter approaches in angular. Lots of examples around. Please show what you have tried. You obviously know about `$filter` or it wouldn't be being injected. Also show relevant html and event handler

Comment: You could use a combination of `ng-repeat` and `ng-if`, though I don't know if I would recommend it for larger data sets.

Comment: @charlietfl I updated my question with a filter that I used on a table.  This allows me to search by anything.  I'm not sure how to make it so I can just search by order # and come up with one result.

Comment: @Asok how would I bring back only 1 result if I'm using ng-repeat?

Comment: thanks to whoever down voted my question.  I'm just new, trying to learn.  :(

Comment: bring up one result in table? Or another dom element?

Comment: I misread, you should definitely be using a filter if you are searching for a record based on user input

Comment: use `$filter` in controller and set for exact match...see docs on how to search specific property only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close already. You just need to update the ng-model of the input to isolate the value you are wanting to filter by. In this case, the order number.

```
<input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" ng-model="query.ordernumber " />
```

Comment: This will not work as requested, potentially giving multiple orders at times. If you add the strict filter `ng-repeat="result in vm.results | filter : query : true "` your answer would be there.

Comment: @buzzsaw Thank you.  It works!  Asok I added what you said.  Thanks to both of you for your help.